# Can't connect to internet in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: usb, internet, ubuntu-gnome

**ping**

```
me@home:~$ ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Name or service not known
```

**lspci**

```
me@home:~$ sudo lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)
```

**apt-get install**

```
me@home:~$ sudo apt-get install lgraph

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lgraph
```

**ifconfig**

```
me@home:~$ ifconfig

enp0s29u1u5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.42.121  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
    inet6 2405:205:818f:10b6:6d17:f005:a807:faba  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 2405:205:818f:10b6:d4c3:6f9:d1a0:3898  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether 02:14:0b:03:ff:31  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 15  bytes 1584 (1.5 KB)
    RX errors 65  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 173  bytes 28069 (28.0 KB)
    TX errors 1  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 78:24:af:bc:a8:a2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 99790  bytes 6000434 (6.0 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 99790  bytes 6000434 (6.0 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I use my android mobile to tether over USB.

[image: connection detected however]

Comment: Are you able to ping IP addresses such as `8.8.8.8`? What's the output for `cat /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: What's the output from `ip route`? You MUST have a `default` route.

Comment: @AzkerM no i cant ping

Comment: If you don't post us the outputs of what we require, it is difficult for us to assist you with the issue. please post the outputs of above commands + `route -n` as well? [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/840853/edit) your question and post the results, not images.

Comment: It appears your connection to the hotspot is fine. Ensure the connectivity to the internet is good, have you tested another device on the same network? Also make sure you have no apps blocking your hotspot and check your Allowed Devices list in your hotspot settings.